# sheet2cal script returns NaN when moved to Calendar

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-calendar-api

Using new Apps script which was built from working Apps script based on sheet2cal. Works but keep getting NaN when results move to calendar.

```js
if (eventID != complete) {
  var currentCell = sheet.getRange(startRow + i, numColumns);
  calendar.createEvent(Purpose + '-' + Visiting, Start, End, { description: +Name + ' | ' + Phone + ' | ' + Email + ' | ' + Details + ' | ' + Insurance });
  currentCell.setValue(complete);
}
```

Calendar Results:

```
Contractor-Ron Layton
Saturday, September 30⋅1:00 – 6:00pm
**NaN** | 9042701111 | Radarb@rath.com | Kia Soul, FL-SUX000, Sales pitch |
```

Answer (score 1):

When I saw your showing script, it seems that `{ description: +Name + ' | ' + Phone + ' | ' + Email + ' | ' + Details + ' | ' + Insurance }`. In this case, I thought that the reason for your current issue is due to `+` of `+Name`. So, please remove this `+` as follows.

#### From:

```
calendar.createEvent(Purpose + '-' + Visiting, Start, End, { description: +Name + ' | ' + Phone + ' | ' + Email + ' | ' + Details + ' | ' + Insurance });
```

#### To:

```
calendar.createEvent(Purpose + '-' + Visiting, Start, End, { description: Name + ' | ' + Phone + ' | ' + Email + ' | ' + Details + ' | ' + Insurance });
```

#### Note:

- In this modification, it supposes that your other variables and the other part of your script are valid. This modification resolves your question of `but keep getting NaN when results move to calendar.`. Please be careful about this.